# Why does VSIX installation fail with warning SizePreCheckEvaluator?

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

When trying to install a Visual Studio extension, I get the following error:

> Pre-check verification failed with warning(s): SizePreCheckEvaluator.

What causes this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target drive may not have enough disk space for the extension.

Search for `SizePreCheckEvaluator` in the log file linked to on the previous error dialog for full details.